# Plotly go.Indicator: change the value color

Tags: python, plotly

I have not find a way to solve this, although searching for it everywhere.

I have an indicator graph made with plotly which has for purpose to a display a single value. I need to change the color of that value, without changing the color of the suffix.

Here is what I have:

```
topchoicename = go.Figure()
    topchoicename.add_trace(go.Indicator(
            mode="number",
            number={"font": {"size": 15},"suffix":top_choice['CarrierName'].iloc[0]},
            value=1,
            gauge={'shape': "bullet"},


            domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        ))
    topchoicename.update_layout(paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                           plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
               
                           autosize=False,
                           width=150,
                           height=20,
                           )
    
    topchoicename.update_traces(align="center", selector=dict(type='indicator'))
```

My question is:

how to change the value color, WITHOUT changing the color of the suffix in the number param. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any solution... tried inspected plotly HTML / javascript as well